# pyspark: not able to install spark.jars.packages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed pyspark in a virtualenv using pip. the requirements file is  below

```
py4j==0.10.7
pyspark==2.4.3
requests==2.22.0
certifi==2019.9.11
```

and have JAVA 8 installed.

the below is my python script which is not working

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName("MyApp") \
  .config("spark.jars.packages", "spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.2") \
  .getOrCreate()

print("Spark Version:",spark.version)
```

I want some packages i am using `spark.jars.packages`

I am getting

```
(venv) simha@gauranga:~/app$ python test2.py 
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/simha/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/simha/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/simha/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.11 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-bb6b433c-c7c1-4ae5-8e79-7a71efa7aa18;1.0
    confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 3062ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
    :: modules in use:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.11;2.4.2

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/simha/.m2/repository/spark/jars/packages=org/apache/spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.2/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.2.pom

      -- artifact spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.11;2.4.2!spark-avro_2.11.jar:

      file:/home/simha/.m2/repository/spark/jars/packages=org/apache/spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.2/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.2.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/simha/.ivy2/local/spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.2/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.11;2.4.2!spark-avro_2.11.jar:

      /home/simha/.ivy2/local/spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.2/jars/spark-avro_2.11.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/spark/jars/packages=org/apache/spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.2/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.2.pom

      -- artifact spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.11;2.4.2!spark-avro_2.11.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/spark/jars/packages=org/apache/spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.2/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.2.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/spark/jars/packages=org/apache/spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.2/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.2.pom

      -- artifact spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.11;2.4.2!spark-avro_2.11.jar:

      https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/spark/jars/packages=org/apache/spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.2/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.2.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.11;2.4.2: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.11;2.4.2: not found]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1306)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.2") \
  File "/home/simha/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/home/simha/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 367, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/home/simha/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/home/simha/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/simha/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/simha/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in _launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
(venv) simha@gauranga:~/app$
```

i can see that package is available

[image]

Where as the below works

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName("MyApp") \
  .getOrCreate()

print("Spark Version:",spark.version)
```

and the output is

```
(venv) simha@gauranga:~/app$ python test2.py 
24/02/19 19:30:28 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark Version: 2.4.3
```

Comment: Typo? Don't put `spark.jars.packages` in the value string. Also, why not use Spark 3 or Java 17?